# AsyncStorage has weird characters in React-Native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to store my users authorization key using AsyncStorage but whenever I do I get weird characters. Here is my relevant code:

```
async function retrieveItem(key) {
    try {
        let retrievedItem =  await AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then(value => retrieveItem = value);
        return retrievedItem;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }   
    return
}

let test = retrieveItem('@authentication')

class AppNavigation extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(test)
...
```

This is the output that I get for test. The item that I want is there under `_55` and I'm able to get it by doing `console.log(test._55)`. I just wanted to make sure I am not doing this correctly. Will the key always be _55 for async storage?

```
{"_40": 0, "_55": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZTk1ODM3NDJlZDI1YjAxMWM4MWFiNWEiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODY4NTY4MjB9.yK0WYuZj7_2Nih7phisi5rmm0y7gF__PMRMEAafIkFk", "_65": 1, "_72": null}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should note use async/await and .then together, both do the same thing.
Try this code instead:

```
async function retrieveItem(key) {
    try {
        let retrievedItem =  await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
        return retrievedItem;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }   
    return
}

let test = await retrieveItem('@authentication')

class AppNavigation extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(test)
```

Edit: the object you got is a promise and you can get its value by doing the async/await syntax or calling .then(...)

Answer (score 0):

its actually Promise Pointer you have to resolve the Promise by await

use it in classes

```
async  componentDidMount() {
       let test =await retrieveItem('@authentication');
       console.log(test);
      }
```

use it in hooks

```
useEffect(async () => {
    let test =await retrieveItem('@authentication');
           console.log(test);
  });
```